# Sublime Phantom 100% width

Tags: html, plugins, sublimetext3

I added a Phantom to the view (via plugin) with the following html string:

```
html = '''
    <body id="my-plugin-feature">
    <style> 
        html, body {

            width: 100%;
            display: block;
        }
        div.error {
            position: relative;
            display: block; 
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #111111;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 3px solid blue
        }
    </style>
    <div class="error">CONTENT</div>
</body>
'''
```

I use `sublime.LAYOUT_BLOCK` for render this Phantom.

But the block is just as width as the word `CONTENT`.
How can i force the block to have 100% width of the Editor view?

Answer (score 0):

`view` has a method called `viewport_extent()`

And HTML in Sublime Plugin can not use `%` as Unit. So I have to use the following to get the pixel width as string:

`width = str(view.viewport_extent()[0])`

EDIT: Set the width as pixel string doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Workaround with padding:

```
width = str(view.viewport_extent()[0]) + "px"

html = '''
    <style>
    .fullwidth {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        padding-left: ''' + width + ''';
    }
    </style>
    <div class="fullwidth"></div>
    <p>My Content</p>
'''
```